# UI only Updating once when using Cubit while an updated list is emitted

Tags: flutter, dart, bloc, emit, cubit

I am adding and removing items to a list that is used to render a data table. But state Is only changing when the first element is added. but it won't rerender for the next clicks. but if i emit a state with [] and then emit the list it render properly.

Following is my Cubit

```
import 'package:bloc/bloc.dart';
import 'package:equatable/equatable.dart';
import 'package:my_app/data/models/activities.dart';
import 'package:my_app/data/repositories/activities_repo.dart';

part 'assign_activity_state.dart';

class AssignedActivitiesState extends Equatable{
  final List<Activities> activities;
  AssignedActivitiesState({required this.activities});

  AssignedActivitiesState copyWith({
     List<Activities>? items,
  }) {
    return AssignedActivitiesState(
      activities: items?? this.activities,
    );
  }

  @override
  // TODO: implement props
  List<Object?> get props => [activities];

}

class AssignActivityCubit extends Cubit<AssignedActivitiesState> {
  AssignActivityCubit() : super(AssignedActivitiesState(activities: []));
  List<Activities> assigned_activities = [];
  loadInitialActivity(String uuid) async{

    try{  assigned_activities = await ActivitiesRepo().getAssignedActivities(childId: uuid);
    print(assigned_activities);
      emit(state.copyWith(items: assigned_activities));
    }
    catch(_){

    }
  }

  addAssignedActivity(Activities activity) async{

    assigned_activities.add(activity);
    emit(state.copyWith(items: assigned_activities));


  }
   removeAssignedActivity(Activities activity) async{

    assigned_activities.removeWhere((item) => item.id == activity.id);
    emit(state.copyWith(items: assigned_activities));

  }
}
```

I have Created a UI Layer With

```
BlocBuilder<AssignActivityCubit, AssignedActivitiesState>(

          builder: (context, state) {
            return ListView(
              padding: const EdgeInsets.symmetric(vertical: 10.0),
              shrinkWrap: true,
              children: [
                Heading(
                  text: "Currently Assigned Activities",
                ),
                Row(
                  children: [
                    ElevatedActionButtonWeb(
                      onTap: () {
                        print("ss");
                      },
                      label: "Remove from Assigned Activities",
                    )
                  ],
                  mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.end,
                  mainAxisSize: MainAxisSize.max,
                ),
                ActivityTable(
                  activities: state.activities,positionedAbove: true,
                )
              ],
            );

          },
        )
```

And Activity Table Renders Like following

```
 Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    List<DataRow> activityRows = [];
    print(widget.activities.length);
    widget.activities.forEach((element) {
      activityRows.add(DataRow(cells: [
        DataCell(widget.positionedAbove
            ? IconButton(icon: Icon(Icons.arrow_downward), onPressed: () {

          context.read<AssignActivityCubit>().removeAssignedActivity(element);
        })
            : IconButton(icon: Icon(Icons.arrow_upward), onPressed: () {


          context.read<AssignActivityCubit>().addAssignedActivity(element);
        })),
        DataCell(Text(element.title!)),
        DataCell(Text(element.ageGroupStart!)),
        DataCell(Text(element.primarySkill!.skill!)),
        DataCell(Text(element.additionalSkills!
            .map((element) => element.skill)
            .toList()
            .join(","))),
      ]));
    });
    print(activityRows.length);
    return DataTable(columns: [
      DataColumn(
          label: Text("Select",
              style: TextStyle(
                  fontStyle: FontStyle.italic, fontWeight: FontWeight.bold))),
      DataColumn(
          label: Text("Activity Name",
              style: TextStyle(
                  fontStyle: FontStyle.italic, fontWeight: FontWeight.bold))),
      DataColumn(
          label: Text("Age Group",
              style: TextStyle(
                  fontStyle: FontStyle.italic, fontWeight: FontWeight.bold))),
      DataColumn(
          label: Text("Primary Skill",
              style: TextStyle(
                  fontStyle: FontStyle.italic, fontWeight: FontWeight.bold))),
      DataColumn(
          label: Text("Sec Skill",
              style: TextStyle(
                  fontStyle: FontStyle.italic, fontWeight: FontWeight.bold))),
    ], rows: activityRows);
  }
```